# How to collect the values of a cell in a worksheet that satisfy a condition and add them to a listbox?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, listbox

I would like an IF ELSE statement to add data values of a cell to a listbox that I have displayed in the worksheet.

Code with regards to the listbox.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    With Sheet1.ListBox1
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .ListFillRange = Sheet2.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, True)
    End With
    
End Sub
    
Sub loaddata()

    Dim listdata As Object
    Set listdata = Sheet1.ListBox1
    Dim tabeldata As Range
    Set tabeldata = Sheet2.Range("Table2")

    With listdata
        .AutoLoad = True
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .List = tabeldata.CurrentRegion.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Listbox displayed on the worksheet with serial numbers
[image]

I would like to put the serial numbers (column A data) into the list if they are pending review - which I denote with a blank in a 'Completed' column P in Table2.
I use a userform to fill in data required and if a case is pending review I leave that 'Completed' segment blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it smth like

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call loaddata
End Sub

Sub loaddata()
    Dim listdata As MSForms.ListBox, tabeldata As ListObject, cl As Range
    
    Set listdata = Sheet1.ListBox1
    Set tabeldata = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")

    With listdata
        .Clear
        .ColumnHeads = False
    End With
    
    For Each cl In tabeldata.ListColumns("Completed").DataBodyRange
        If cl.Value = "" Then
            listdata.AddItem cl.Offset(, -1).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, i've added in the code and adjusted to recall the correct sheet and table and columns but it does not seem to be automatically adjusting the list box contents. It still lists all serial numbers in my first column. Am i recalling the sheets wrong?

Comment: @ChrisH I think you should just call `loaddata()` from `Sub Workbook_Open()` (added to solution)

Comment: I think ive got some progress, but i think the "For Each cl in tabledata,listcolumns.." doesnt seem to be working when i tried adjusting the code runs but doesnt seem to run the for loop. 

    For Each cl In tabeldata.ListColumns("P:P").DataBodyRange
        If cl.Value = "" Then
            listdata.AddItem cl.Offset(, -14).Value
        End If
    Next

Comment: `.ListColumns("P:P")` will not work. You need to use field name in the `.ListColumns()` such as `ListColumns("Completed")` (see in the head of the table) or number of field inside the table `ListColumns(2)`

Comment: Managed to get it to work via a command button to run the sub routine. I think when my data is on another sheet, when the Sub Workbook_Open() runs, I find I always need to play the code manually on ALT+F11 to update the listbox.